# Built-in HP ProBook 430 G5 keyboard almost dead and doesn’t behave as expected even after replacement keyboard has been installed?

Tags: keyboard, bios, hardware-failure

I have an HP ProBook 430 G5 (Windows 10). Suddenly, my keyboard has stopped working. No liquids, drops or any other accident happened.

Actually, 90% of the keys do not work at all and the rest of them work in a wrong way.
E.g. I press <kbd>G</kbd> and I get `H` on the screen etc.

What I have already tried, but with no luck:

1. Delete and reinstall keyboard drivers
2. Run hardware diagnostics from BIOS
3. Boot from a Linux live USB and try to type some text on console
4. Update BIOS

I have to note that an external USB keyboard works fine.

So, I ordered a new keyboard for my laptop and I replaced it, but I have the same problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Next tests, cable, battery. Failed cable is a prime cause, but a swollen battery pressing components against each other is a common cause.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
The new keyboard had also the cable that connects it to the laptop, so i don't know if this is the problem. If the problem is to the onboard keyboards connector i am afraid that i cannot replace it. Also, i cannot check the battery, it's not removable.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop for proper diagnostics.

Comment: @DavidPostill i am afraid that their diagnosis would be "yes, we tried a new keyboard, does not work, we had to change the motherboard and the CPU, total cost 700 Euros!". That's why i am trying to figure what else i can try by my shelf.